# Is there a way to fire click event on 'span' using fireEvent in react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, antd, react-testing-library

I'm using ant Design select component to create my custom select. I'm trying to test (using react-testing-library) if the selected element is correctly removed after clicking the 'x' icon inside the tag. Unfortunately in the test element is not being removed. I think it's the issue with the 'remove' element since it's not a button, but a span (I can't change it since it's built-in somewhere inside ant design select component)

I've tried to use click event, also mouse down and up events but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
const renderMultiselect = () => {
  const { container } = render(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Multiselect
        items={items}
        optionKey="code"
        optionName="name"
        selected={selectedItems}
        testId="types"
        testIdOptionKey="code"
        label="Types"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </I18nextProvider>,
  );
  return container;
};

describe('Multiselect', () => {
  it('allows to remove elements', () => {
    const container = renderMultiselect();
    const selected = container.querySelector('.ant-select-selection__rendered ul');
    const removeIcon = selected.firstChild.querySelector('.ant-select-selection__choice__remove');
    fireEvent.mouseDown(removeIcon);
    fireEvent.mouseUp(removeIcon);
    //also tried: fireEvent.click(removeIcon)
  });
});

//that's how the remove 'button' looks inside the DOM
<span class="ant-select-selection__choice__remove">
   <i aria-label="icon: close" class="anticon anticon-close ant-select-remove-icon">
      <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" class="" data-icon="close" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
         <path d="M563.8 512l262.5-312.9c4.4-5.2.7-13.1-6.1-13.1h-79.8c-4.7 0-9.2 2.1-12.3 5.7L511.6 449.8 295.1 191.7c-3-3.6-7.5-5.7-12.3-5.7H203c-6.8 0-10.5 7.9-6.1 13.1L459.4 512 196.9 824.9A7.95 7.95 0 0 0 203 838h79.8c4.7 0 9.2-2.1 12.3-5.7l216.5-258.1 216.5 258.1c3 3.6 7.5 5.7 12.3 5.7h79.8c6.8 0 10.5-7.9 6.1-13.1L563.8 512z"></path>
      </svg>
   </i>
</span>
```

The expected result is to trigger event which will remove the first element inside the multiselect from selected items. 
Here's how the Ant Design Select component looks like: 
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: `fireEvent.click` on a `span` will fire a click event. I think the problem is that the Ant Design component is not listening for that particular event. In my experience, when you have complex 3rd party components the best way to handle them in tests is to mock them. I wrote a little about it here https://www.polvara.me/posts/testing-a-custom-select-with-react-testing-library/ it's about `select` but I think it applies to your use-case too

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought that it would be tricky to test and so far it really made my blood boil :) Your post is very useful so I will try to mock the select and see how it goes :)